# Should I sand my traditional wood floor before staining?

Tags: flooring, floor, hardwood-floor, wood-filler

I live in a flat with traditional wood flooring boards. They are pretty much in  good condition although some have gaps of a few mm. Anyway we want to fill those gaps probably using Bona Gap Master (I heard it's good) and sawdust + resin. My main worry is to stain the floor with a darker colour and screw it all up. What is the procedure to fill gaps and stain the floor?

[image]

Comment: Are you asking what the correct procedure is if you decide to stain the floor? Or what will look better?

Comment: @Jax I am asking for the procedure to stain the floor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you sand it you'll eliminate the charming deep grain and rough-sawn artifacts. I wouldn't sand anything but what seems like an injury hazard. I'd also leave the gaps empty. A hard-floor vacuum will keep it clean enough.

To the second question, staining without sanding will give very dramatic color variation in the open grain and saw kerfs. You'll get a nice rustic look. If you prefer a more modern, uniform color, sand it well to an even smoothness after you fill the gaps.

Having said that, I'm voting to close the question as *primarily opinion-based*.

Comment: I interpreted the intent of the question as "what is the proper procedure" as opposed to "what will look better." I don't know anything about finishing wood floors and might ask the same question. However, as with any trade, I suppose "the proper procedure" could sometimes be a matter of opinion. Perhaps we should give the OP the opportunity to clarify what type of answer is being sought: procedural or opinion?

Comment: Fair enough. I updated my answer to address that point further.

Comment: @isherwood A rustic finish is acceptable and more appropriate for a Victorian flat.

Comment: I'd love to see a photo when it's done. Consider adding one to your question later.